# Put two blank page after table of content

Tags: blank-page

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage[square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{float,here}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},textfont=it]{caption}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}



\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.1 cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.28cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.65 cm }
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.4in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.4in}

\input{rgb}
\pagestyle{myheadings}


\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\def\fps@table{htbp}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.5}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.4}
\newcommand{\FH}{{\textsc{\tiny FH}}}

\floatsep 36pt
\textfloatsep 36pt
\intextsep 36pt


\def\vitalsecdepth#1{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{#1}
   \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}}
\vitalsecdepth{3} % 5/13/92 kelliher

\sloppy



\begin{document}

\include{first-page}
\include{statem}
\include{certi1}
\include{acknow2}

%\clearpage
\baselineskip=20pt
%\include{TOC}



\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{1ex}}{\bfseries\chaptername~\thecontentslabel:\quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}[]
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tableofcontents




%\null\cleardoublepage
%\newpage
%\newpage
%\cleardoublepage
%\clearpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}

%\justify

\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}
\include{chap4}
\include{chap5}
\include{chap6}
\include{chap7}

\markboth{}{}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage



\baselineskip=20pt


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document is not passible to test since we haven't files which you include in your document. Beside this you should load `graphicx` instead of `graphics`. Also, for question you need  prowide MWE, a small but complete document, which we can compile and reproduce your problem. Meaning that most of your preamble, all commented code lines had to be removed.   BTW, `\cleardoublepage
\null\newpage
` after `\tableofcontents` is what you looking for.

Comment: Please try with `\clearpage\hbox{~}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\clearpage\hbox{~}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage`, understand that this looks ugly, but hope it works....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that works now adds 2 blank pages after table of contents I have included comments `FOR BLANK PAGE` the lines I added

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
%\usepackage[square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{float,here}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},textfont=it]{caption}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
%%% FOR BLANK PAGE
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
%%%%%

%\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
%\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}



\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.1 cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.28cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.65 cm }
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.4in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.4in}

\input{rgb}
\pagestyle{myheadings}


\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\def\fps@table{htbp}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.5}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.4}
\newcommand{\FH}{{\textsc{\tiny FH}}}

\floatsep 36pt
\textfloatsep 36pt
\intextsep 36pt


\def\vitalsecdepth#1{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{#1}
   \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}}
\vitalsecdepth{3} % 5/13/92 kelliher

\sloppy



\begin{document}

\include{first-page}
\include{statem}
\include{certi1}
\include{acknow2}

%\clearpage
\baselineskip=20pt
%\include{TOC}



\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{1ex}}{\bfseries\chaptername~\thecontentslabel:\quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}[]
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\tableofcontents
%% FOR 2 BLANK PAGES
\afterpage{\blankpage}
\afterpage{\blankpage}



%\null\cleardoublepage
%\newpage
%\newpage
%\cleardoublepage
%\clearpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}

%\justify

\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}
\include{chap4}
\include{chap5}
\include{chap6}
\include{chap7}

\markboth{}{}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage



\baselineskip=20pt


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to insert \newpage or \clearpage twice in the beginning of "chap1"?
So that chapter "chap1" starts with 2 empty pages.
It's more a workaround than a solution but maybe give it a try.